# Dimension of packets sent through a socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have implemented a system similar to BitTorrent, and I would like to know at what size I should set the packets of each chunk. I was not able to find how BitTorrent does it, what size packets they use. I currently use 100 kilobyte packets, is that a lot?

Comment: Do you use TCP or UDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP breaks data into packets automatically. You don't have to worry about the size of network packets.

The size of a TCP packet is constrained by the MTU (maximal transfer unit) of the network, typically around 1500 bytes. If you were making a game or a multimedia program where low latency is important you might have to keep in mind that data is sent in packets, but for a file transfer program it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a TCP packet. It's a byte stream. Under the hood it is broken into segments, in a way that is entirely out of your control, and further under the hood those segments are wrapped in IP packets, ditto.

Just write as much as you like in each write, the more the better.